# Jquery ajax post request is sent just one time on a click action

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a button :

```
<a href="#" id="buttonNew" class="buttonNew">{{ 'buttonNewText'|trans }}</a>
```

And an ajax action when i click on this button :

```
    $(function(){
        $("#buttonNew").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ path('ajax_load_new_note_form') }}",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#homeLeft').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The first time i click on my button, a post request is sent, so it's OK. But when i click again no other request is sent. When i reload my page, the click send the request and not the next clicks.

What am i missing ?

Thank you by advance

Comment: Is `$('#homeLeft').html(data);` replacing the `#buttonNew` element?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click','#buttonNew',function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('ajax_load_new_note_form') }}",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#homeLeft').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can accept it if worked for you, just click on the check symbol to the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(function(){
    $("#buttonNew").click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('ajax_load_new_note_form') }}",
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I try EH_warch and salih0vicX solutions. Only EH_warch solution works for me.

Comment: I am happy you have found a solution for your issue. Please consider marking his answer as good answer and give him some points. Some other users could use his marked answer ... Thank you :)